# Positioning tooltip on specific element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a button (in #DTCOption section)that when pressed results in a tooltip :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelectOptions" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" runat="server" data-role="button" Class="custom-btn" data-inline="true" data-theme="c" data-transition="pop" UseSubmitBahavior="false" href="#" data-mini="true" OnClientClick="SelectOptions()" >GO</asp:LinkButton>
<div id="tooltip" style="display:none;">Please use valid options.</div>
```

When the button is pressed I show the tooltip:

```
    function SelectOptions() {
            $('#tooltip').toggle();
    }
```

However the tooltip is not displaying where I want it. I am trying to add the following code so that it is positioned correctly but no change results.

```
    $(document).on("pageshow", "#DTCOption", function () {
        $("#tooltip").tooltip({ position: { of: "#lnkSelectOptions", at: "right" } })
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/5y5ZD/) will help you.

JS

```
    $('.tipme' ).tooltip({
                              show: { effect: "blind", duration: 800 },
                          position:
                                   {
                                    my: 'left center',
                                    at: 'right center'       
                                    }
    });

$('.buttondiv').click(function(){
      if ( $(".ui-tooltip").length > 0 )
       {
        $('.tipme').tooltip('close');
        }
        else
       {
        $('.tipme').tooltip('open');
        }
                                  });
```